# Appending string from subclass

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on a little project of mine which utilises Java Swing. What I'm trying to do is to recreate Battleships. Problem is that whenever I push a button, I don't know how to append a string in a JTextarea from another class whilst I'm writing my ActionListener in my grid class.

Par example:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

private GridPanel gridPanel;
private TextPanel textPanel; 

public MainPanel(String name,Color color) {
    gridPanel = new GridPanel("Grid", 400, 400, 10,color, name);
    textPanel = new TextPanel();
  }
}
```

This is my main panel class which instantiates both classes. Now I've got an ActionListener inside my gridPanel which currently prints output to my console. I want to print it on my textPanel.

classes (gridPanel)

```
public class GridPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton[][] grid;

public GridPanel(String panelName, int xWidth, int yHeigth, int buttonSquared, Color color, String name) {
            grid = new JButton[buttonSquared][buttonSquared];
            grid[0][0].addActionListener;
            grid[i][j].setText("~~~");
            grid[i][j].putClientProperty("column", i);
            grid[i][j].putClientProperty("row", j);
            grid[i][j].putClientProperty("name", name);
            grid[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    System.out.println("clicked column " + btn.getClientProperty("column")
                            + ", row " + btn.getClientProperty("row") + " Name of the panel you've clicked on: " + btn.getClientProperty("name"));
                }
            });
           this.add(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```

(TextPanel)

```
public class TextPanel extends JPanel{

JTextArea textArea;

public TextPanel() {
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setSize(200,400);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 11));
    textArea.append("Test!");
    this.add(textArea);

  }

}
```

As you can see inside my ActionListener, it has a simple sysout which prints a given key's value. How do I append the TextPanel so that it shows what Im currently printing to my console?

ps. I simplified my code for the question.

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4XQU.png)

Comment: Look up MVC or Model-Viewer-Controller and then utilize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to build an MVC framework, here's a quick and dirty solution:

**MainFrame**:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public MainFrame() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));

        TextPanel tp = new TextPanel();
        GridPanel gp = new GridPanel(tp);

        add(tp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(gp,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**TextPanel**:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TextPanel extends JPanel {
    JTextArea textArea;

    public TextPanel() {
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setSize(200,400);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 11));
        textArea.append("Test!");
        this.add(textArea);
    }

    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }

}
```

**GridPanel**:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GridPanel extends JPanel {

    TextPanel tp = null;

    public GridPanel(TextPanel panel) {

        tp = panel;

        JButton btn = new JButton("Click Me");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                JTextArea ta = tp.getTextArea();
                ta.setText(ta.getText() + "\n" + "Added!!!");
            } 
        } );
        add(btn);

    }

}
```